# How to re-render an SVG in d3?

Tags: jquery, svg, hyperlink, d3.js, calendar

I am adapting the d3 example calendar located here: http://bl.ocks.org/4063318

[image]

and I'm trying to make it so that each day in the calendar is hyperlinked.

To do so, I added an anchor tag around each "rect", like so:

```
var rect = svg.selectAll(".day")
  .data(function(d) { return d3.time.days(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
  .enter()
  .append("a")                                   //my new line of code
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://stackoverflow.com") //my new line of code
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "day")
  .attr("width", cellSize)
  .attr("height", cellSize)
  .attr("x", function(d) { return week(d) * cellSize; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return day(d) * cellSize; })
  .datum(format);
```

This will link each rect to this website. However, I want the link to be data dependent.
So, instead of the line above:

```
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://stackoverflow.com") //my new line of code
```

I use:

```
  .attr("class", "rectAnchor")
```

I do this so that I can select the rectAnchor and then access their rect child, then set the xlink:href attribute, like so, in the following code:

```
d3.csv("dji.csv", function(error, csv) {
  var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
    .rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].Close - d[0].Open) / d[0].Open; })
    .map(csv);

  rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "day " + color(data[d]); })
      .attr("dyanmiclinktext", function(d) { return data[d]; })  //my new line of code
      .select("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + percent(data[d]); });


  $(".rectAnchor")                                       //my new line
  .attr("xlink:href", function(){                             //my new line
     return "http:/127.0.0.1/subdir/" + $(this).children("rect").attr("dynamiclinktext"); //my new line
  });

});
```

Now, when I do that, there are no working hyperlinks and another two undesirable things happen: First, the link inside the anchor tag says xlink:href"URL" instead of href:"URL" . Secondly, if I change the line .attr("xlink:href", function(){ to .attr("href", function(){ , it still doesn't work. 
So, I'm wondering, is this because the svg has already been rendered and I need to re-render it with these new and improved anchor tags?  Or is there something else I'm missing?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

***addendum:***

```
   $(".rectAnchor").attr("xlink:href", "http:/127.0.0.1/subdir/" + $(this).children("rect").attr("finer"));
```

generates:

```
<a class="rectAnchor" xlink:href="http:/127.0.0.1/subdir/undefined">
<rect class="day" width="17" height="17" x="170" y="51" finer="group1" fill="#aec7e8">
<title>2012-03-13: group1</title>
</rect>
</a>
```

(Notice the undefined and the 'xlink:href' instead of just 'href')

```
 $(".rectAnchor").attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "http:/127.0.0.1/subdir/" + $(this).children("rect").attr("finer");});
```

generates:

```
 <a class="rectAnchor" xlink:href="http:/127.0.0.1/subdir/group2">
 <rect class="day" width="17" height="17" x="153" y="34" finer="group2" fill="#aec7e8">
 <title>2012-03-05: group2</title>
 </rect>
 </a>
```

Neither are hyperlinked in the displayed svg (i.e. mouse pointer exhibits no difference and clicking does nothing.)
I also changed 'xlink:href' to 'href' in the 2 cases. this outputted the same as above, but with the 'xlink:' missing. However, as before, nothing was hyperlinked. Thanks.

Comment: have you made sure that you if you are appending an <svg:a> element? Try `.append("svg:a")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you're using `$(".rectAnchor")`, you're now in jQuery world – not d3 world.

The `attr()` function in jQuery doesn't work with functions, the way d3's `attr()`.

You need simply:

```
$(".rectAnchor").attr(
  "xlink:href",
  "http:/127.0.0.1/subdir/" + $(this).children("rect").attr("dynamiclinktext")
);
```

Assuming there are no other issues, this should work.

**EDIT:**

Actually, I didn't notice `$(".rectAnchor")` yields multiple elements. You need a hybrid of your previous attempt and my suggestion above:

```
$(".rectAnchor").each(function(i, element) {
    var $el = $(element);// $(this) would work too
    $el.attr("xlink:href", "http://127.0.0.1/subdir/" + $el.children("rect").attr("dynamiclinktext"));
});
```

Note that where you have `http:/127...` you actually need `http://127....` (i.e. you're missing a slash).

Finally, are you sure that wrapping SVG elements with `<a>` tags actually works for making them links? It may, but I've never tried it. If you're not sure, you should try it out as a standalone test (in, say, jsFiddle) with manually generated SVG (i.e. no javascript).

Comment: Thanks for your help, meetamit. However, it's still not working. I'll edit my original post.

Comment: I got it to work using my original code. I had mistakenly commented out the line: 
     `.attr("xlink:href", "http://stackoverflow.com") //my new line of code`

Changing the href link with the jquery code I used initially worked. The important part is that there is an "xlink:href" attribute added when the original <a> is added. If only a bare <a> is added initially, then adding the xlink:href attribute afterwards does not seem to work. Hope this helps.